# how graduate the axis of the graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data tables:

**vah_p_1**

```
x       y
0       4
0.25    5
0.27    6
0,29    7
0.31    8
0.33    10
0.34    13
0.36    16
0.37    20
0.38    23
0.39    28
0.4     37
0.41    43
0.42    55
0.43    67
0.44    81
0.45    94
0.46    118
0.47    143
0.48    187
0.49    225
```

**vah_o_1**

```
  x      y  
-17.2   -9
-14.2   -8
-9.27   -7
-6.9    -6
-4.09   -5
 0      -4
```

I need to build data for two tables in one graph(code below).

```
vah_p <- read.table(file='vah_p_1',header =TRUE)
y <- log2(vah_p$y)
x <- vah_p$x
mat_p <- data.frame(x,y)
error_p <- lm(y  ~ x, mat_p)
error_p <- tidy(error_p)

vah_o <- read.table(file='vah_o_1',header =TRUE)
y <- log2((vah_o$y)*(-1))
x <- vah_o$x
mat_o <- data.frame(x,y)
error_o <- lm(y  ~ x, mat_o)
error_o <- broom::tidy(error_o)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(vah_p, aes(x = x,  y = y)) +
 geom_point() + geom_point(data = vah_o, aes(x = x,  y = y))
p
```

After compilation I will get a graph.
[image]
<sub>(source: [savepice.ru](https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/2/717552a7421503e58b4f906006f149c9-full.png))</sub>

This schedule is very bad. I tried to graduate the axis  the graphics that looked better, but I did not succeed. Help please.

Comment: What is good schedule?

Comment: It is necessary that the chart looks like this [this](http://solo-project.com/sites/default/files/uploads/volt_ampernaya_harakteristika4.gif)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to change the scale as I understand the problem use

```
ggplot() + ylim(min, max)
```